# Output sort | uniq in sections rather than waiting for complete input

Tags: bash, uniq

I am using `sort` and `uniq` to process the output from a script, i.e.

```
script | sort | uniq -c
```

The script outputs data in chunks of maybe 1000 lines before performing more processing and then outputting another 1000 lines. The chunks are completely independent.

It would be useful for me to be able to process the output in 1000 line chunks through `sort` and `uniq` and output the results to the console before continuing the process.

Another way of putting this is that I want `sort` to clear it's buffer after processing 1000 lines. Is this possible in any way?

Comment: But, were it possible, you would be sorting inside each chuck only...

Comment: the issue is not with buffering, but with sort's purpose: it sorts all lines of stdin, so it has to wait for the last, i.e. until EOF. to sort each chunk independently, you would have to split `script`'s output and pass it to individual `sort` processes. How you could easily achieve that with bash, I don't know

Comment: yes, exactly, so I want to sort each chunk individually. Is there a way to break the pipe to cause an EOF, effectively?

Comment: Is it "maybe 1000 lines" or is it exactly the same number of lines each time?

Comment: yes, it will always be the same number of lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    i=0
    while IFS= read -r; do
        printf "%s\n" "$REPLY"
        if ((i >= 999)); then
            break
        fi
        ((i++))
    done > >(sort | uniq -c)
    if ((i==0)); then
        # previous `while read` returned no lines. We're done.
        break
    fi
done | cat
```

This reads up to 1000 lines at a time from stdin, and applies `sort | uniq -c` for each block of 1000 lines.  You'd use it something like this:

```
./yourscript | ./read1000.sh > output.txt
```

---

Before anyone dings me for a *Useless use of cat award*, this `cat` is necessary to sync the output from the `sort | uniq -c` process substitution, if the output is going to the terminal instead of redirected to a file or pipe.

Comment: +1, nicely done; you may have put it there for clarity, but the `IFS=` is not strictly needed, since `$REPLY` always receives the whole line including leading and trailing whitespace (the `-r`, however, IS needed to turn interpretation of `\ ` escape sequences off).

Comment: @mklement0 I didn't know that about `$REPLY`.  Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure; I wasn't sure either; your answer prompted me to research the issue.

Comment: @mklement0 I couldn't find any mention of this `$REPLY` behaviour in the bash manual, though I can confirm your observation definitely stands up to test.  Didi you find this documented anywhere?

Comment: No, I merely tried it out, namely in bash 3.2.51, 4.2.25, and 4.2.46 and since they all behave the same - and the behavior arguably makes sense (the need to still use `-r` was a little unexpected to me) - I assumed the behavior is here to stay; you're right, though, all the manual says is `If no names are supplied, the line read is assigned to the variable  REPLY` and a variation of that.

Comment: @mklement0 I guess the [source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/read.def) is the documentation here ;-)  See the comment starting at line 756.

Comment: Great find; I've never looked at how the sausage is made before.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! I learned a lot from this too.